# Script para buscar y copiar archivos a otra ubicación

Tags: script, vbscript

Soy muy nuevo en scripting y no se como encarar esta situación:

Tengo las siguientes carpetas en red, todas con miles de archivos con nombres como 1-ABX123:

- V:\G\
- V:\I\
- Y:

Necesito buscar nombres de archivos específicos y, si los encuentro, copiarlos en otra carpeta de red de esta manera:

- Si el archivo se encuentra en la carpeta V:\G, el archivo debe copiarse en la carpeta G:.
- Si se encuentra en la carpeta Y: o en V:\I, tengo que copiarlo en la carpeta I:.

¿Existe alguna forma sencilla de hacerlo?

Edit:

Hice uno que es bastante rústico, funciona, pero me gustaría sacarle la opción de elegir el disco y directamente que busque en los 3 y si encuentra el archivo en un disco, lo copie y salga.
Y no se si es posible hacer que lea un txt con múltiples nombres de archivos y los vaya buscando uno por uno.

```
@echo off
set ruta1=V:\G
set ruta2=V:\I
set ruta3=Y:\
set rutag=G:\
set rutai=I:\
:retorno
echo.
set disco=0
set cadena=exit
echo= 1. V:\G
echo= 2. V:\I
echo= 3. Y:\
set /p disco=Unidad de Disco (1,2,3):
if %disco%==0 goto retorno
echo.
:error
set /p cadena= Archivo (nombre o parte del mismo):
if %cadena%==exit goto error
echo.
echo.
if %disco%==1 (goto discog) else (goto discoi)
:discog
where /r %ruta1% *%cadena%* > resultados.txt
set /p copiar=<resultados.txt

xcopy %copiar% %rutag%
del resultados.txt
echo.
echo.
set /p seguir= ¿Volver a buscar? (s/n):
if %seguir%==s (goto retorno) else (goto next0)
:discoi
if %disco%==3 goto discog
where /r %ruta2% *%cadena%* > resultados.txt
```

```
set /p copiar=<resultados.txt
xcopy %copiar% %rutai%
del resultados.txt
echo.
echo.
set /p seguir= ¿Volver a buscar? (s/n):
if %seguir%==s (goto retorno) else (goto next0)
:next0
if %seguir%==S (goto retorno) else (goto exit)
echo.
echo.
exit
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Publica lo que has intentando. De ahi podemos partir.

Comment: Gracias @CandidMoe ! Acabo de agregar el código que he intentado